# Render multiple elements in-line if max-height has been reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm rendering multiple `div` elements dynamically using `PHP`. Those div elements get rendered inside a container div that has `max-height: 300px;` This container div has `width: 500px;`, and the div elements that I'm rendering inside it have `width: 10px;`.

Currently, all divs are getting rendered below one another, and when they reach the maximum height of `300px`, they get rendered outside the container div element. Instead, these elements should start a new column at the top of the container div when the first column fills the container div.

Comment: Please include some specific HTML code that you're having trouble with. Offering relative and vague examples of values is not helpful.

Comment: "I hope someone gets me, if not, I will post a image about the situation." Don't post only image, post CODE too...

Comment: Do they have to go in order top-to-bottom first before they move over to the next column?  Or can it go 1-2, then 3-4, then 5-6, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to generate a separate container div for each column, and add the CSS rule `display: inline-block` to the containers.

```
<div class="container">

<?php

    $image_directory = '/path/to/your/images/';

    $images = array(
        $image_directory . 'image_1.jpg',
        $image_directory . 'image_2.jpg',
        $image_directory . 'image_3.jpg',
        # and so on...
    );

    $count = 1;

    foreach( $images as $image ) {

        if( $count == 1 ) {    
            echo '<div class="image-column">';
        }

        echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';

        if( $count == 5 ) {    
            echo '</div>';
            $count = 1;
        }

        $count++;
    }
?>

</div>
```

And then in your CSS

```
.image-column {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This isnt working for what I want; I made a image to show you want I want, like I see in this image number 6 wen't up to the top because there is no more space below 5: http://puu.sh/7qjs9.png

Comment: @user3041757 You have to generate the columns with PHP. I've edited my answer to show how you might go about doing this. Of course, you have to know in advance what the images are.